# Advice on where to store and save angular data

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a wizard-config app with 3 pages. Each page has the same MasterController but different html templates. Each html templates has a different controller, say ControllerOne, ControllerTwo, and ControllerThree.

I load the data via MasterController and I'd like the data and any changes the user makes to be stored temporarily until the save & finish step on the final page. Trouble is as the user goes through the pages, MasterController is called each time and each time it fetches the data and overwrites the user's changes.

I've thought about attaching this data to a service or rootScope but the data initialization still happens in MasterController so the data would still be overwritten when each view is loaded.

Any advice on how I should go creating this functionality or restructuring my app to support this?

EDIT:

To be clear on the service issue. I don't know where to initialize it. If I do it in Controllers 1,2 or 3 my data is reinitialized each time the view changes so that doesn't work. I can't do it in app.run() either because I need to get to MasterController in order to get the necessary ID to make my HTTP request. I can't do it in MasterController because that too is called on each page switch.

Ideally I'd have a view within a view so that only the inner view changes. However angular does not support nested views and I'm trying to find a way around this without having to use angularUI.

Comment: I say Service or localstorage

Comment: Just move your data initialization code into a service and store the data there, you can also define your methods that use $http to send the data ultimately in your service and just inject it into your controller and call it where appropriate http://plnkr.co/edit/ABQsAxz1bNi34ehmPRsF?p=preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the data being loaded from the server on each page change and overwriting the user data, I used an "extend" function (like jQuery's) to extend the server data with the user data on each load. Page changes would call my service(that stores the temporary data) to save the data there and the final "save and finish" button would push the data in the service to the server.